# C++ Copy Constructor when Class has an array of another Class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

I'm still learning about classes, copy constructors, and overloaded operators so any advice/help/->s is appreciated!!!

I am trying to make a copy constructor with the class Test2 which has a private member variable from another class, Test1. I have commented in the code where the copy constructor that is giving me the business is located.

Here is the error I get when compiling:

```
assOp.cpp: In copy constructor 'Test2::Test2(const Test2&)':
assOp.cpp:102:25: error: passing 'const Test2' as 'this' argument of 'int Test2:
:getNum()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  setNum(original.getNum());
                         ^
assOp.cpp:103:27: error: passing 'const Test2' as 'this' argument of 'char* Test
2::getChar()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  setChar(original.getChar());
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Test1
{
    public:
        Test1();
        Test1(const Test1& original);
        int getNum();
        char *getChar();

        void setNum(int x);
        void setChar(char y[]);


    private:
        int num;
        char *ch;

};

class Test2
{
    public:
        Test2();
        Test2(const Test2& original);

        void setNum(int x);
        void setChar(char y[]);

        int getNum();
        char *getChar();

    private:
        Test1  foo;


};

int main()
{

    Test1 a;
    Test2 b;



    return 0;
}

Test1::Test1()
{
    num = 1234;
    ch = new char[5];
    strcpy(ch,"test");
}

Test1::Test1(const Test1& original)
{
    int length = strlen(original.ch); 

    num = original.num;
    ch = new char[length + 1];
    strcpy(ch, original.ch);
    ch[length] = '\0';

}

int Test1::getNum()
{
    return num;
}

char *Test1::getChar()
{
    return ch;
}

void Test1::setNum(int x)
{
    num = x;
}

void Test1::setChar(char y[])
{
    int length = strlen(y); 
    ch = new char[length + 1];
    strcpy(ch, y);
    ch[length] = '\0';

}

Test2::Test2()
{

}

//Sassy copy constructor that thinks its better than me
Test2::Test2(const Test2& original)
{

    setNum(original.getNum());
    setChar(original.getChar());


}

void Test2::setNum(int x)
{
    foo.setNum(x);
}

void Test2::setChar(char y[])
{
    foo.setChar(y);

}

int Test2::getNum()
{
    return foo.getNum();
}

char *Test2::getChar()
{
    return foo.getChar();
}
                       ^
```

Comment: you could try pasting the error message into your favourite search engine.

Comment: See http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs202/Lectures/modules/m09-const/slides.php?print

Comment: That is awesome, thank you!

Comment: @PcAf, out of curiosity what or how did you search to get that exact of an answer. My searches usually lead here with the result only being a loose connection to my question.

Comment: @BuckWheat I searched for *c++ call function on constant object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by

```
    int getNum();
    char *getChar();
```

Since these functions are not `const` member function, they cannot be used on a `const` object. As a general rule, make all the getter functions `const` member functions.

```
    int getNum() const;
    char const* getChar() const;
```

Comment: You can also overload functions by const-ness, if you need a non-const accessor as well.  For instance, you can have both `const char* getChar() const;` and `char* getChar();`.